# Simple Ruby Program...Help Needed

Tags: ruby

Just trying to write a simple Ruby program here. I'm trying to get the program to ask for the user's favorite number and then suggest a new favorite number that's one greater. What's wrong with the code below?

```
puts "hey, whats your favorite number?" 

favnumber = gets.chomp 

newfavnumber = favnumber.to_i + 1 

puts "how about " + newfavnumber "?"
```

Comment: This was easy enough, but in the future, it'd be better to also include the _error message_ you get.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts "how about " + newfavnumber "?"
```

First of all, you probably wanted a `+` before the `"?"` there. The way this is written now, it parses as `puts("how about " + newfavnumber("?"))`, i.e. you're calling a function called `newfavnumber`, which is obviously not what you want.

However if you change it to `puts "how about " + newfavnumber + "?"`, which you presumably intended, it still won't work: `newfavnumber` is a number and `"how about "` is a string. In ruby you can't add numbers to strings. To fix this you can call `to_s` on `newfavnumber` to convert it to a string.

A better way to write this would be using string interpolation: `puts "how about #{newfavnumber}?"`. This way you don't need to call `to_s` because you can use any type inside `#{}`.

Comment: Also, how do I get spaces between strings.  If I define firstname and lastname, how do I get puts firstname + lastname such that it displays "firstname lastname" instead of "firstnamelastname"?  Thanks again guys.

Comment: @Mariogs `puts "#{firstname} #{lastname}"`

Comment: How do I do it without the #{} notation?  Also, what does that notation do, exactly?

Comment: @Mariogs By adding a space (`" "`) between the two strings. What `#{}` does is it evaluates the expression inside the braces and inserts the result in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `+` after `newfavnumber` and a conversion to string.

```
puts "how about " + newfavnumber.to_s + "?"
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Adding a `Fixnum` to a `String`? I think you'd have to do this: `puts "How about #{newfavnumber}?"`

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: No. I don't know Ruby that well yet. I was going to put it in anyway, but... I didn't. Sigh.